# Separating with \ instead of ; when using arrays for multiple sumifs criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I tried to write a formula like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Table!$J:$J;Table!$G:$G;{"K12*";"K22*"};Table!$H:$H;{"K01";"K03";"K04";"K05";"K06";"K07";"K09";"K10";"K15"}))/1000
```

but it didn't work and then I found a solution to write \ instead of ; in one array when separating criteria

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Table!$J:$J;Table!$G:$G;{"K12*"\"K22*"};Table!$H:$H;{"K01";"K03";"K04";"K05";"K06";"K07";"K09";"K10";"K15"}))/1000
```

and this worked.

Can someone please explain to me why exactly does it work like this?
I would like to understand how things work instead of just blindly copying a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this explaination to this behaviour:

[image]